# Admin Access for a Rails App w/partitioned database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, admin

I've been searching for some leads on this issue but so far have come up dry.  I'm about to start working on building out some pretty basic admin functionality (mostly CRUD) for a Rails 4 app that uses a partitioned database (PG schemas).

Ideally I'd like to start out using something like rails_admin or active_admin to at least give GUI-based access to database records to non-developer admins, but I'm not sure of the following two points:
1. Is it possible/feasible to configure or customize one of those solutions to work with a partitioned database?
2. Is the amount of work involved minimal, or extensive enough to warrant considering building an admin interface from scratch?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you checkout the `apartment gem` which enables multi-tenant functionality to an app.

https://github.com/influitive/apartment

Comment: We're actually already using apartment.  The issue is that in the application, a schema is loaded based on either the subdomain present in the request or based on the current user's account (not all of our pages are accessible via subdomain).  All of that logic lives in a set of filters that run before nearly every request, but they won't work for an admin user since said user won't have any information attributed to it that would enable the correct schema to be loaded.  I imagine there's a solution

Comment: (sorry I added the comment prematurely)...in customizing the controllers for either RailsAdmin or ActiveAdmin, but I'm unsure of how to tackle that in an elegant, or at least not terribly hacky way.

Comment: Is the admin user suppose to access data of a subdomain or of all the domains ?

Comment: All (any?) of the domains.  Is there a way to configure the search path to be different for admin access versus regular user access?